# Q on Python serialization/deserialization

Tags: python, serialization, binary

What chances do I have to instantiate, keep and serialize/deserialize to/from binary data Python classes reflecting this pattern (adopted from RFC 2246 [TLS]):

```
   enum { apple, orange } VariantTag;
   struct {
       uint16 number;
       opaque string<0..10>; /* variable length */
   } V1;
   struct {
       uint32 number;
       opaque string[10];    /* fixed length */
   } V2;
   struct {
       select (VariantTag) { /* value of selector is implicit */
           case apple: V1;   /* VariantBody, tag = apple */
           case orange: V2;  /* VariantBody, tag = orange */
       } variant_body;       /* optional label on variant */
   } VariantRecord;
```

Basically I would have to define a (variant) class VariantRecord, which varies depending on the value of VariantTag. That's not that difficult. The challenge is to find a most generic way to build a class, which serializes/deserializes to and from a byte stream... Pickle, Google protocol buffer, marshal is all not an option.

I made little success with having an explicit "def serialize" in my class, but I'm not very happy with it, because it's not generic enough.

I hope I could express the problem.

My current solution in case VariantTag = apple would look like this, but I don't like it too much

```
import binascii
import struct

class VariantRecord(object):
  def __init__(self, number, opaque):
    self.number = number
    self.opaque = opaque
  def serialize(self):
    out = struct.pack('>HB%ds' % len(self.opaque), self.number, len(self.opaque), self.opaque)
    return out


v = VariantRecord(10, 'Hello')
print binascii.hexlify(v.serialize())

>> 000a0548656c6c6f
```

Regards

Comment: Why aren't you happy with it?

Comment: What is wrong with pickle? Why do you care about somewhat esoteric methods of using C++ when you are using Python? What would you like to have happen? It seems like you want a dense method of storing data, but It is hard to tell what you are really trying to generalize.

Comment: I have to implement http://zinfandel.levkowetz.com/html/draft-ietf-p2psip-base-08. Hope that says it all. I have to meet the line protocol, which is binary, but not pickle compliant.

I'm not happy with it, because it isn't generic enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. For the variable length structure use a fixed format
   and just slice the result.
2. Use `struct.Struct`

e.g. If I've understood your formats correctly (is the length byte that appeared in your example but wasn't mentioned originally present in the other variant also?)

```
>>> import binascii
>>> import struct
>>> V1 = struct.Struct(">H10p")
>>> V2 = struct.Struct(">L10p")
>>> def serialize(variant, n, s):
    if variant:
        return V2.pack(n,s)
    else:
        return V1.pack(n,s)[:len(s)+3]

    
>>> print binascii.hexlify(serialize(False, 10, 'hello')) #V1
000a0568656c6c6f
>>> print binascii.hexlify(serialize(True, 10, 'hello')) #V2
0000000a0568656c6c6f00000000
>>>
```

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the hint, but V1 isn't serialized correctly. The "<0..10>" notation has been adopted from the TLS RFC. It is required to preceed each variable length array of bytes by an element indicating the _current_ length of the structure. In case V1 the expected result would have to look like in my sample.

Comment: I can't see how my V1 result differs from yours (except that I used a lower case h in 'hello'). The current length is included in the result: that's what the 'p' format does in Struct.

Comment: Ah, ok. Wasn't aware of the "p". Thanks